# what is user name means in upgradation of magento 2.2.4 to magento2.2.6?

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.6

[image]

[image]

what is user name means in upgradation of magento 2.2.4 to magento2.2.6 ?
I want to upgrade magento 2.2.4 to magento 2.2.6. 
what is user name means in this upgradation.

Please see the below pic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here username means , your magento.com account's public key. When you run composer ( upgrade / require ) from magento root folder you will be asked to provide these credentials.

Also you can save these in your project root directory in auth.json file for later use, and magento will not ask for these credentials again and again.

Check this URL to see where you can find it these tokens  :

[Access Keys](https://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/account/account-magento2-access-keys.html) and [Account Guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html)

Comment: please clarify where I found the magento.com account's public key

Comment: login to your magento.com account and check this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html check this link

Comment: After that I run the command "composer update". It takes so much of time and I open my website it shows following error "puppetkart.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: please found the above pic I have the following error

Comment: it seems some .htaccess issue did you check logs ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to magento.com
2. go to my account page.
3. click on Marketplace link ( It might be redirect in marketplace so after redirection click on back in browser and again click on market place).
   [image]
4. Click on Access keys
   [image]
5. 1st key is username and 2nd key is password.

Comment: After that I run the command "composer update". It takes so much of time and I open my website it shows following error "puppetkart.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500" –

Comment: uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); from app/bootstrap.php and check what is error here

Comment: please found the above pic I have the following error

Comment: login in cpanel and check server log file

Comment: can you please tell me where i will the server log file

Comment: there will be name error.log search it